# Wifi disappeared

Tags: wifi, software-installation, bluetooth, repositories, iphone

I have an installation of Elementary OS working. Now my wifi conncection disapeared, and I do not have cable connection. I tried to pair my iphone to get and internet conection, but without success. I tried bluetooh pair, but nothing. I tried to use recovery mode, nothing (it asks for internet reposistories). I tried to mount the iso installation of Elementary OS as a repository, but have got errors.

I've got the wifi card information as

`usb@1:5 802.11 Realtek wlam adapter`

In my opinion, Elementary OS is missing an improvement. It's an internet based system, it cannot stay without internet.

For an extra information, it's a dual boot system. Internet works perfectly in windows!

Comment: While I can appreciate the trouble you've experienced, there’s no actionable information here to offer a solution. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network`, which will show network hardware details, as well as the brand and model of computer you’re using? This will make it much easier for someone to help solve this problem 

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with a reinstall.

To answer your question,

````
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx2418c6aee6f4
       serial: 24:18:c6:ae:e6:f4
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.13 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11```

about the system

```wmoreira@compaq:~$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'
System Information
    Manufacturer: Compaq
    Product Name: 420
    Version: Default string

wmoreira@compaq:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #2 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
````

I hope this helps to improve the system. Thanks a lot!